# how to fix source not found message for coldfusion eclipse remote debugging?

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, remote-debugging

I have eclipse with coldfusion builder installed, and I set up the various screens - RDS and coldfusion debug settings in preferences, project properties and set the server up there.

It seems like it is almost working, the RDS screens work, and I can start debugging, but when it hits my breakpoint I get a blank source page that says 'Source not found.' with a button for 'Edit source lookup path'.

If I click the button, it shows my workspace tree, not much I can do with that, but I can add a path so I tried adding a path to the root of my project on the web server.   When I ok that, for an instant I see some code appear in the source viewer, then it disappears and I have the source not found message again.   If I click edit, my path is not there... ??

Comment: Does refreshing the project help? When you go to your ColdFusion Project in navigator, right click and choose "Coldfusion Server" is your servername correct and does it have the proper source tree? -just guesses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what fixed it exactly, but I just went through all the different settings screens and re-defined all the debugging paths, etc. and it finally started working.